# Solve this differential equation in terms of $f(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions

I need to solve the equation and express it in terms of $f(t)$:

$$y''-3y'+2y=f(t) \hspace{40 pt} y(0)=2 \hspace{10 pt} y'(0)=-6$$

Now, $f(t)$ is just a random function, it can be anything. Using Laplace transforms, I got $$(s^2-3s+2)L[y]-2s+12=L[f(t)]$$

The real problem is how I can find the transform of $f(t)$, and moreover, how I can invert the equation back, to solve it.

Comment: Hint: The product of Laplace transforms is the Laplace transform of the convolution.

Comment: You can also solve this by variation of parameters. It will leave you with an integral in terms of $f$ and some explicit exponentials.